TableGenerator(identifier table) strategy in entity framework core + SQL Server
Is there a built-in way to support TableGenerator ids in Entity Framework? If not, what is the best way to implement it?
Table generator(identifier table) document in Hibernate:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch06.html#identifiers-generators-identity

Defines a primary key generator that may be referenced by name when a
generator element is specified for the GeneratedValue annotation. A
table generator may be specified on the entity class or on the primary
key field or property. The scope of the generator name is global to
the persistence unit (across all generator types).
Example 1:

@Entity public class Employee {
    ...
    @TableGenerator(
        name="empGen", 
        table="ID_GEN", 
        pkColumnName="GEN_KEY", 
        valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE", 
        pkColumnValue="EMP_ID", 
        allocationSize=1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=TABLE, generator="empGen")
    int id;
    ...
}


Here is the sample implementation along with my idea for its implementation.
Create a new table in your database to store the generated keys. The table should have at least two columns: one for the key name (e.g., "Table1") and one for the current key value.
Define a new class to represent the TableGenerator entity in your Entity Framework model. This class should map to the TableGenerator table in your database.
public class TableGenerator
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public int NextId { get; set; }
}

Add a DbSet for the TableGenerator entity to your DbContext class.
public DbSet<TableGenerator> TableGenerators { get; set; }

Create a method in your DbContext class to generate a new key for a given table name.
public int GenerateKey(string tableName)
{
    var generator = TableGenerators.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TableName == tableName);
    
    if (generator == null)
    {
        generator = new TableGenerator { TableName = tableName, NextId = 1 };
        TableGenerators.Add(generator);
    }
    
    generator.NextId++;
    
    SaveChanges();
    
    return generator.NextId;
}

Use the GenerateKey method to generate unique keys for your entities.
var newId = dbContext.GenerateKey("Table1");

var entity = new MyEntity { Id = newId, Name = "Entity1" };

dbContext.MyEntities.Add(entity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();

How can the above code be improved and a locking mechanism added?
I use SQL Server as a database provider

Maybe this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences

@SvyatoslavDanyliv no sql-server

no without sequence, with a table

@VanasisB, sequences looks much better. With addtional table it is possible via Stored Procedure. Note that it will be point of failure - many inserts for different tables can be blocked.

Why? Using tables is only used when the database doesn't have sequences. That's not a J2EE feature at all, it's a MySQL liability as almost all other databases have sequences. What you ask is an attempt to fix some missing feature. We can't guess what that missing feature is

the above code be improved by getting removed completely. That's just a hack, not a feature. Explain the actual problem instead, and why you can't just use an Identity or Autonumber column, or you can't use NEXT VALUE FOR SomeSequence as the PK column's default value

@PanagiotisKanavos yes you are right we have great sequence in sql-server but its for learning purpose

The lesson then is that the table generator is only used to cover up missing database features. Even then, the value must be generated in the database, not using round-trips to the client, because a round-trip's duration is thousands if not millions of times larger than the time it takes to execute a single command. The lock you intend to use would take thousands of times longer, resulting in huge blocking issues. A single UPDATE SeqTable SET ID=ID+1 OUTPUT inserted.ID WHERE Seqname=@table is atomic and returns the new ID immediately. That's still not as scalable as a sequence though

The other part of the lesson is that there are legitimate key strategies that could require part of the key to come from the database and part from the client, essentially assigning a range of IDs to the client, to reduce roundtrips. You can configure this with eg the  UseHiLo strategy.

@VanasisB An explicit key generator is only useful if you want to generate sequential numbers that are unique over some other property. A standard example is invoice numbers that start at 1 each year. (But of course the invoice would still have a unique PK, preferentially an identity column.) Or if for some outlandish reason you want to generate non-numeric and non-guid primary keys. Years ago, I posted an answer that may serve as a basic idea to start from.

Despite all possible issues, IMO the question deserves upvotes, because it was well formulated and also useful, because it's good for others to be aware of these issues, and alternatives, when trying something similar.

Here is a better implementation for table generator in EF Core with overriding the default ValueGenerator:
Define a new class to represent the TableGenerator entity in your Entity Framework model
public class TableId
{
    [Key]
    public required string TableName { get; set; }
    public int NextId { get; set; }
}

ValueGenerator
public class TableGenerator : ValueGenerator<int>
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override int Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var dbContext = entry.Context;
            var tableName = entry.Metadata.GetTableName() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
            var tableIdValue = entry.Context.Set<TableId>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.TableName == tableName);

            if (tableIdValue == null)
            {
                tableIdValue = new TableId { TableName = tableName, NextId = 1 };
                entry.Context.Set<TableId>().Add(tableIdValue);
            }
            else
            {
                tableIdValue.NextId++;
                dbContext.Entry(tableIdValue).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return tableIdValue.NextId;
        }
    }
}

Add a custom entity without identity column
public class CustomEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}

And Finally OnModelConfiguring overriding to add new generator
public class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TableId> TableIds { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomEntity>().Property(e => e.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasValueGenerator<TableGenerator>();
    }

Update 1
As per Panagiotis Kanavos' suggestion, I have updated the Next(EntityEntry entry) method with the following changes for exlusive lock:
    public override int Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var dbContext = entry.Context;
            var tableName = entry.Metadata.GetTableName() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

            // Exclusive lock the record
            var tableIdValue = dbContext.Set<TableId>()
                .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM TableIds WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE TableName = {tableName}")
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (tableIdValue == null)
            {
                tableIdValue = new TableId { TableName = tableName, NextId = 1 };
                entry.Context.Set<TableId>().Add(tableIdValue);
            }
            else
            {
                tableIdValue.NextId++;
                dbContext.Entry(tableIdValue).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return tableIdValue.NextId;
        }
    }

Update 2
without locking the table:
    public override int Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {

        var dbContext = entry.Context;
        var tableName = entry.Metadata.GetTableName() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var nextId = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>(@$"
                        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableIds WHERE TableName = {tableName})
                            INSERT INTO TableIds(TableName, NextId)
                            OUTPUT inserted.NextId
                            VALUES({tableName},{1})
                        ELSE
                            UPDATE TableIds SET NextId = NextId + 1 
                            OUTPUT inserted.NextId 
                            WHERE TableName = {tableName}
                        ").AsEnumerable()
                        .First();

        return nextId;
    }


That's a very bad implementation that guarantees duplicate values if even two clients try to generate keys at the same time. It's no better than the HiLo or Sequence generation strategies already available.

@PanagiotisKanavos, can you provide me with more tips on how to improve my code? I would like to know how to implement a locking mechanism to prevent duplicates. I understand that this may not be the best choice, but I am doing this for learning purposes. Thank you.

The lock you need is meant to prevent multiple connections from reading the same ID at the same time which means it needs to be an exclusive database lock. If you use an UPDATE ...  that returns the new value with the OUTPUT clause you don't need explicit transactions for this.

more tips I already described the options. EF is an ORM, not a database driver. Besides there's no application O(bject) in this case. Client-controlled locks (ie transactions) cause extensive blocking so you should try to use SQL for high traffic operations like this. UPDATE SeqTable SET ID=ID+1 OUTPUT inserted.ID WHERE Seqname=@table will always return a new ID even if multiple clients execute it at the same time, without locking the table for long.
